# Attributes Python Adding a Set value

Tags: python, python-2.7

for Essay class I need The attribute that stores the grade should be public and always be betweem 0.0 and 4.0. What I was thinking was set_grade(self,grade) but how do you implement an if statement to make sure that it return a number 0.0 between 4.0

```
class Assessment:

        grade = 0
        def get_grade(self):
        return self.grade

    """This operation is creating a concrete subclass of Assessment"""  
class Essay (Assessment):   

    """This operation is getting the grade the grade for the Essay class which will return a grade"""

        def get_grade(self):
        return self.grade

    """This operation is creating a TeamProject Class with an individual score and a team score grade"""    

class Teamproject(Assessment):

         ind_sc = 0

          ts_sc = 0
    """This operation is getting the grade to individual score and team score and returning the average"""

        def get_grade(self):
        return (self.ind_sc +self.ts_sc) / 2
```

Comment: It should be noted that your indentation in completely broken, and your docstrings are in the wrong place.

Comment: doc string like??? @LennartRegebro

Comment: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/ http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/python-docstrings/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how do you implement an if statement to make sure that it return a number 0.0 between 4.0

Try this:

```
  def set_grade(self, grade):
      if grade < 0.0 or grade > 4.0:
          raise ValueError('out of range')
      self.grade = grade
```

If you use this in *Assessent* and *Essay*, the *TeamScore* will also be in-bounds.

Hope this helps :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
if 0.0 <= grade <= 4.0:
    <do something>
else:
    raise ValueError("Error message)
```